# Exponentiation with basis $b>1$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

Let's suppose we've just defined exponentiation from axioms in real numbers with rational powers (I mean defining integer powers, nth rooth,, and then rational powers).
Let $b>1,x\in\mathbb{R},r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Let $R_x=\{b^t\mid t\in\mathbb{Q}\wedge t\leq x\}$.

I was trying to prove that if $x$  is rational, $\sup R_x=b^x$.

I then got to some place in which I had to prove that if $r<s$ then $b^r<b^s$. How can I prove that part (I only need that implication)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction on natural exponents first, then use that to show negative integers exponents. Finally, note that the inverse of an increasing function is also increasing (fairly easy to prove), and use that to show the result for all rationals.